# Why does my distance matrix between leaf nodes from a .gv file result in an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, networkx

How to get a distance matrix between leaf nodes from a .gv file?
I'm trying to obtain the shortest distance between leaves in an unweighted graph.

I have tried this:

```py
def compute_distance_matrix(graph):
    leaf_nodes = [node for node in graph.nodes() if graph.degree(node) == 1]
    leaf_labels = [node.split('s')[1] for node in leaf_nodes]
    distance_matrix = {}
    for i, node1 in enumerate(leaf_nodes):
        for j, node2 in enumerate(leaf_nodes[i+1:], i+1):
            if nx.has_path(graph, node1, node2):
                distance = nx.shortest_path_length(graph, node1, node2)
                distance_matrix[(leaf_labels[i], leaf_labels[j])] = distance
            elif graph.has_edge(node1, node2):
                distance_matrix[(leaf_labels[i], leaf_labels[j])] = 1
    return distance_matrix
```

but it returns an empty dict.

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] along with sample input and the exact expected result?

Answer (score -2):

```
def compute_distance_matrix(nw):
    tree = Tree(nw)
    leaves = tree.get_leaves()
    leaf_labels = [leaf.name for leaf in leaves]
    distance_matrix = {}
    for i, node1 in enumerate(leaves):
        for j, node2 in enumerate(leaves[i+1:], i+1):
            distance = node1.get_distance(node2)
            distance_matrix[(leaf_labels[i], leaf_labels[j])] = distance
    return distance_matrix
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).